# My node js application is working in local along with nginx is working finebut After local development, deploying to Amplify results in an empty page

Tags: aws-amplify

I developed a Node.js application on my local machine with an Nginx server, and it worked flawlessly. However, after pushing the code to CodeCommit and deploying the Amplify frontend, I'm faced with an issue where only an empty page is displayed.

In the empty sheet, I got the title only:

Please resolve the issue. I was using Node 20.8.0 version, and also, I attached the `index.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Ruff Greens</title>
    <!-- For download react dev tools -->
    <!-- <script src="http://127.0.0.1:5173/"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-query/dist/react-query.production.min.js"></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>


I hope this helps.
```

Comment: **Chrome:**
Amplify page screenshot: ![I got the title font only after I getting only the empty page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJEO3.png)

**Firefox:**
This is a Firefox output: ![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qmyZ.png)